# Using the Windows Facebook SDK the FBUser class misses information

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, win-universal-app, facebooksdk.net

Using the [Windows SDK for Facebook](http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/) I've managed to log in and set the correct permissions to retrieve some info.

This was done using this code

```
FBSession sess = FBSession.ActiveSession;
sess.FBAppId = FBAppId;
sess.WinAppId = WinAppId;

// Add permissions
sess.AddPermission("public_profile");

// Do the login
await sess.LoginAsync();
```

Now the problem is that I can only retrieve a small bit of information from the FBUser and not all the fields that exists within it, for example:

```
sess.User.Name; // This WORKS
sess.User.Id; // This WORKS
sess.User.FirstName; // DOESN'T WORK
sess.User.LastName; // DOESN'T WORK
sess.User.Locale; // DOESN'T WORK
...
```

Comment: Some sort of feedback would be lovely instead of a simple downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FBUser associated with the ActiveSession is from the beginning ONLY populated with the data that you get from the initial "did login work"-request (which is a standard request to the [/me Uri](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me&version=v2.4)).

This only includes:

- Full Name
- Facebook ID

To get more data about the user you need to make use of the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api), and include the fields you're interested in as a parameter in the request.

This is one example how it could look like to update the current FBUser with the first_name, last_name and locale of the user.

```
// This is the current user that we're going to add info to
var currentUser = FBSession.ActiveSession.User;

// Specify that we want the First Name, Last Name and Locale that is connected to the user
PropertySet parameters = new PropertySet();
parameters.Add("fields", "locale,first_name,last_name");

// Set Graph api path to get data about this user
string path = "/me/";

// Create the request to send to the Graph API, also specify the format we're expecting (In this case a json that can be parsed into FBUser)
FBSingleValue sval = new FBSingleValue(path, parameters,
  new FBJsonClassFactory(FBUser.FromJson));

// Do the actual request
FBResult fbresult = await sval.Get();

if (fbresult.Succeeded)
{
  // Extract the FBUser with new data
  var extendedUser = ((FBUser)fbresult.Object);

  // Attach the newly fetched data to the current user
  currentUser.FirstName = extendedUser.FirstName;
  currentUser.LastName = extendedUser.LastName;
  currentUser.Locale= extendedUser.Locale;
}
```

Please note that the sample code only includes a very minimum amount of verification. Since this includes network calls more should be added.